# JavaScript form validation not working as intended

Tags: javascript

Good morning,

I'm working on some simple form validation.   Whenever I submit my form, the error message appears, but I can repeatedly spam the button for numerous error messages.  Is there a way I can change this to only show the error message once? I've also noticed that even if I populate both fields it will still flash quickly in my console with the error log but not show the error.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```js
 var uname = document.forms['signIn']['userame'].value;
 var pword = document.forms['signIn']['password'].value;

 function validateMe (e) {
  if (uname.length || pword.length < 1 || '') {
  var container = document.getElementById('error-container');
  var errorMsg = document.createElement('div');
  errorMsg.className = 'error-message';
  errorMsg.innerHTML = '<span class="heading-large">Please enter a valid username or password</span>';
  container.appendChild(errorMsg);
  console.log('An error occured');
  return false;
  } 
  
 }
```

```html
<form id="signIn" action='#'>
    <div class="boxed left-floater">
     <h1 class="heading-large margin-top">Sign in</h1>
     <div id="error-container"></div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label-bold" for="username">Username</label>
      <input class="form-control log-in-form-control" id="username" name="username" type="text">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label-bold" for="password">Password</label>
      <input class="form-control log-in-form-control" id="password" type="password" name="password">
     </div>
     <div>
      <a class="right-floater forgotten-password" href="forgottenpassword.html">Forgotten Password</a>
      <button class="button clear right-floater" type="submit" onclick="validateMe();">Sign In</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wu6ancwb/)

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle / CodePen?

Comment: have you tried using prevent default at the top of the function? anyway that if condition seems bad. Can you provide your html or a fiddle

Comment: Yes give me a moment

Comment: did you try to read values of uname and pword by document.getElementById ?

Comment: I've added a fiddle, though it doesn't seem to work at all - any ideas?

Comment: @FarukT I could try it this way, I just assumed using forms would be the better way of doing it.

Comment: You have any plugin attached for form validation?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be clearing the contents of your `container` to avoid duplication of elements. Below are few things to note:

- You were trying to get **userame** instead of **username** in your fiddle. May be spelling mistake.
- Keep `input type=submit` instead of `button`
- Pass the `event` to your `validateMe function` to prevent the default action of post.
- Move the variables within the function to get the actual value all the time

```js
function validateMe(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var uname = document.forms['signIn']['username'].value;
  var pword = document.forms['signIn']['password'].value;
  var container = document.getElementById('error-container');
  container.innerHTML = ''; //Clear the contents instead of repeating it
  if (uname.length < 1 || pword.length < 1) {
    var errorMsg = document.createElement('div');
    errorMsg.className = 'error-message';
    errorMsg.innerHTML = '<span class="heading-large">Please enter a valid username or password</span>';
    container.appendChild(errorMsg);
    console.log('An error occured');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="signIn" action='#'>
  <div class="boxed left-floater">
    <h1 class="heading-large margin-top">Sign in</h1>
    <div id="error-container"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label-bold" for="username">Username</label>
      <input class="form-control log-in-form-control" id="username" name="username" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label-bold" for="password">Password</label>
      <input class="form-control log-in-form-control" id="password" type="password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="right-floater forgotten-password" href="forgottenpassword.html">Forgotten Password</a>
      <input value="Sign In" class="button clear right-floater" type="submit" onclick="validateMe(event);" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/wu6ancwb/3/)**

**Edit** - `if condition` was failing and have updated it accordingly

Comment: Thanks very much, though the issue now seems to be that even if there's anything in the input boxes, it'll still throw the error.

Answer (score 1):

this is full work code

```js
var uname = "";
var pword = "";

function validateMe(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  uname = document.forms['signIn']['username'].value;
  pword = document.forms['signIn']['password'].value;
  if (uname.length || pword.length < 1 || '') {
    var container = document.getElementById('error-container');
    var errorMsg = document.createElement('div');
    errorMsg.className = 'error-message';
    errorMsg.innerHTML = '<span class="heading-large">Please enter a valid username or password</span>';
    container.appendChild(errorMsg);
    console.log('An error occured');
    return false;
  }
return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="signIn">
  <div class="boxed left-floater">
    <h1 class="heading-large margin-top">Sign in</h1>
    <div id="error-container"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label-bold" for="username">Username</label>
      <input class="form-control log-in-form-control" id="username" name="username" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label-bold" for="password">Password</label>
      <input class="form-control log-in-form-control" id="password" type="password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="right-floater forgotten-password" href="forgottenpassword.html">Forgotten Password</a>
      <button class="button clear right-floater" type="submit" onclick="validateMe(event);">Sign In</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: did you try it @Xoog ??